# Referencing a python package installed with pip

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm working on a django project which uses a package called django-google-storage.

I installed the package into a virtualenv using

```
pip install django-google-storage
```

Now I want to reference the package from within my app -

```
from django-google-storage.storage import GoogleStorage
```

But of course I can't because there's hyphens in the name ([invalid syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)).

I've never come across this before - I might install a package with hyphens in the package name (eg `pip install django-grappelli`), but the package is always saved to the virtualenv with a valid identifier in the name (eg 'grappelli').

What should I do to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import importlib
themodule = importlib.import_module('django-google-storage')
```

But, according to the [readme on github](https://github.com/budurli/django-google-storage):

> It' [*sic*] just a compilation of django-storages and boto to improve
>   you abilities to use Google Storage.

I don't think the author intended for you to import this module.

Comment: concur the author did not intend for you to import the module directly. However +1ed for the importlib reference. I dorked with this for a bit trying to get it to import, I was barking up the *.pth tree and trying to import it through boto. I knew 'however' there was some python magic for this. Thats it `importlib.import_module` thats it thanks.

Comment: Thanks @wim That's really helpful. Do you know why someone would write a module they intended not to be imported? (i.e. am I missing a good reason not to import the module)?

Answer (score 1):

This module is not intended to be imported directly. It is intended to override the django storage class.

**django/core/storage.py**

```
class Storage(object):
    """
    A base storage class, providing some default behaviors that all other
    storage systems can inherit or override, as necessary.
    """
```

So follow [these instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-google-storage/) you need to:

Modify your settings.py and:

1. add 'django-google-storage' to your INSTALLED_APPS
2. put 'django-google-storage.storage.GoogleStorage' in DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE.
3. add GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and GS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

That should be it.

Comment: I wanted away of differentiating between django's media files and it's static files something like - `StaticGoogleStorage = lambda: GoogleStorage(location='static')`

Answer (score 0):

You should not import this module. Set the 'django-google-storage.storage.GoogleStorage' class as your `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` and you're done